# How to sum two lookupvalue results in Power Pivot

Tags: excel-formula, dax, data-modeling, powerpivot

In a sales report I want to sum the result of two lookup results. I have two tables that are related (Kürzel & Vertreter; Kürzel & Vertreter 2). However only one relationship can be active the same time which is why I either get the result of relationship 1 or relationship 2... I want to have the sum of both relations though, as seen in the picture:

[image]

I already tried to play around with the relationships and also tried to use the lookupvalue function. However, I didn't get the results wanted so far.

What I've tried:

```
=
LOOKUPVALUE ( Table1[Agentur_Netto in EUR]; Table1[Vertreter]; Table2[Kürzel] ) +
LOOKUPVALUE ( Table1[Agentur_Netto in EUR]; Table1[Vertreter-2]; Table2[Kürzel] )
```

Answer (score 0):

While only one relationship can be active at a time, it is possible in a calculate function to tell it what relationship to use via the USERELATIONSHIP function.

To show a built up example, since showing the step calculations is helpful for testing

```
Main Relationship:= SUM( Table1[Agentur_Netto in EUR] )
Other Relationship := CALCULATE ( SUM( Table1[Agentur_Netto in EUR] ), USERELATIONSHIP( Table2[Kürzel], Table1[Vertreter-2] ) )
Together:= [Main Relationship] + [Other Relationship]
```